# Add props as an HTML attribute in a React.js component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I recently started using Next.js and Tailwindcss. I want to create a custom component that can be used as follows -

```
<CustomComponent> Hello World </CustomComponent>
```

While searching for how to use this, I came across an answer which said -

```
const CustomComponent = props => {
  return (
    <>
      <div {...props} className="text-red-900" />
    </>
  )
}
```

In my example, the `CustomComponent` will simple make the text-color to a shade of red.

I can now use this component as `<CustomComponent> Hello World </CustomComponent>`.

What I don't understand is this line - `<div {...props} className="text-red-900" />`. I couldn't find anything like this in the reactjs docs.

Is this an appropriate way of passing props as HTML attributes? How does it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are equivalent components:

```
const CustomComponent = (props) => {
  return <div className="text-red-900" {...props} />;
};

// props={prop1,prop2,className}
const CustomComponent = ({ ...props }) => {
  return <div className="text-red-900" {...props} />;
};

const CustomComponent = ({ prop1, prop2, className }) => {
  // className will be overridden if its valid
  return <div className="text-red-900" prop1={prop1} prop2={prop2} className={className} />;
};
```

Note that better to use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (for object literals) **after** the inline style (`className`) which makes it more generic.

As for **why spreading the property is a valid syntax**?

You have a [Spread Attributes explained](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes) in the docs, remember that JSX is converted to `React.createElement` which accepts the `props` as an argument.

- [JSX In Depth](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)

Comment: Some people consider props spreading as an anti-pattern:

https://vhudyma-blog.eu/react-antipatterns-props-spreading/

Comment: All claims in this blog arent so accurate when you use types which is basically every modern project.